# Get max value and label in series after zoom in JS HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working off this example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

And I'm manually calling a zoom (the modified chart has two series) with:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(Date.UTC(2007,1,0), Date.UTC(2008,1,0))
```

and now I'd like to get the maximum value of the series in this range, as well as the label/date of that point. I can get the maximum value by:

```
maxInRange = chart.series[0].dataMax
```

but I can't figure out how to find the date/label of the point. I can call and arbitrary data point:

```
chart.series[0].xData['222']
```

which returns a date, but I was looking for something like:

```
chart.series[0].xData[maxInRange]
```

(doesn't work) or similar to get the date point of the max value.

Cheers and thanks for the help!

- UPDATE Yo!- 
  So Now I thought this might work

First find the index of the dataMax value by:

```
maxDateY = chart.series[0].yData.indexOf(maxInRange)
```

which will return the index of where the max is in the y data, then pass that to the xdata as in:

```
maxDateX = chart.series[0].xData[maxDateY]
```

So that's cool and all, but unfortunately I don't think the yData.indexOf call is restricted to the range set by the setExtremes command. So it returns the first matched instance within the whole dataset. Close, but no cigar.

Any other thoughts? Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sebastian's solution works fine.
To focus on max values and get the label/date you could use:

```
events:{
                afterSetExtremes:function() {
                    var minAxis = this.min,
                        maxAxis = this.max,
                        points = this.chart.series[0].points,
                        max = points[0].y,
                        xValue = 0,
                        label = '';

                    $.each(points, function(i, p) {
                        if(p.x >= minAxis && p.x <= maxAxis) {
                            if(p.y > max) {
                                max = p.y;
                                xValue = p.x;
                            }
                        }
                        maxDate = new Date(maxAxis);
                    });
                    label = new Date(xValue);
                    $('#info').html(' MAX: ' + max + ' Label:' + label);
                }
            },
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Just as a note to anyone else, toss this groovy events:{} in the xAxis. Cheers!

Comment: Also, if the max happens to be at the first point in the series putting:, if (xValue == 0){label = new Date (minAxis)} else{label = new Date(xValue); } for the label helps avoid returning a 0, or the incorrect date of 1970.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch afterSetExtremes on xAxis and then iterate on each point of serie, comparing min/max values.

```
xAxis: {
        events:{
            afterSetExtremes:function() {
                var minAxis = this.min,
                    maxAxis = this.max,
                    points = this.chart.series[0].points,
                    min = points[0].y,
                    max = points[0].y;

                $.each(points, function(i, p) {
                    if(p.x >= minAxis && p.x <= maxAxis) {
                        if(p.y > max)
                            max = p.y;

                        if(p.y < min)
                            min = p.y;
                    }
                });

                $('#info').html('MIN: ' + min + ' MAX: ' + max);
            }
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        minRange: 14 * 24 * 3600000 // fourteen days
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/23brwuxb/1/